# Can I drop the second "having" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Can I drop the second *having* in this sentence? :

> So, having looked through your posts and **having** read all the materials that you referred me to, I came to the conclusion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course you can drop the second "having":

> So, having looked through your posts and read all the materials that you referred me to, I came to the conclusion...

is perfectly fine and, in fact, better than repeating the word. The first instance of "having" can do double duty for both phrases, and it's even what the ear expects.

Comment: Umm - Robusto: there is no "of course" about it. You can indeed coordinate at either level, but to a non-native speaker this is not obvious, as your "of course" suggests.

Comment: @Colin Fine: That's one way to interpret what I said. Another is read "of course" as "certainly" in that sentence.

Comment: to me, "of course" always has an implication that it is obvious or already known, or that it should be so. Perhaps it doesn't to you.

Answer (score 2):

To me, repeating the word 'having' would be used to emphasize the fact that all the materials were read when the only thing expected by the listener was looking through the posts.

Comment: Or, the second 'having' could be used to emphasize that reading the materials is a different task than looking through the posts. Depending on the context, this may or may not be obvious.